# Two internal hard drives

Tags: system-installation

I have burned a Ubuntu DVD to install. I want to install it on my alternative, internal D drive,  NOT my normal C drive!

When I reboot and put in the DVD it starts my windows on C drive again. What should I do?

Comment: You need to boot from the DVD, not just put it in. Check the board manual for exact instructions.

Comment: do you have two physical drives or two partitions on one drive? Windows used d: "drive" for either.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the computer to boot from your DVD drive. While your system is booting up (POST-ing to be precise), it should let you to select device to boot from. (pressing F12 works for many PCs.)
You may also try changing/overriding boot options in your BIOS. To get to BIOS on most PCs you have to stroke DEL while booting up.
 Your PC or motherboard manual should tell you how to enter BIOS if it's something exotic